# React Nested Routing by `:id`

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a blog style app with an "articles" page that has a list of posts which will render by `postId`.  I have gotten the urls to generate and even my small `<Post />` component to render, but when a post page renders the Articles content doesn't go away and the post content just renders below it.  How do I fix this?

I have
`App.js`:

```
    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/articles">
            <Articles />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

`Articles.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    Link, 
    useRouteMatch, 
    Switch, 
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Post from '../Components/Post';
import Banner from './Banner';


const Articles = () => {
    let match = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div className='Articles'>
            <Banner title='Articles'/>
            <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/geojsons`}>Geojsons</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
                    Props v. State
                </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/:postId`}>
                    <Post />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Articles;
```

`Post.js`:

```
function Post() {
    let { postId } = useParams();
    return <h3>POST - Requested topic ID: {postId}</h3>;
  }

export default Post;
```

Screen shot of problem page:
[image: Articles page with Post content]

This screenshot shows the page after you click on an article link.  The `Post` content is what I have in the dashed red box and everything above it should only be a part of the Articles page.

I know it is only a couple files but to make it easier to mess with I put a simplified version of the repo on [github](https://github.com/rwegener2/portfolio_bug).  No styling or anything just an html version of the problem.

Comment: can you post your complete articles.js file and if you can attach an image it would be helpful.

Comment: Try add exact to all your routes

Comment: @FridayAmeh adding exact to all my routes makes the `Post `pages return as totally empty
@Dlucidone I added that extra content!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want Article and Posts pages to be separate, you need to decouple your post route from Article route and render it in App.js instead of Articles.js

```
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route> 
      <Route path="/articles/:postId">
            <Post />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/articles">
        <Articles />
      </Route>

   </Switch>
```

and in Article.js

```
const Articles = () => {
    let match = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div className='Articles'>
            <Banner title='Articles'/>
            <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/geojsons`}>Geojsons</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
                    Props v. State
                </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped